# Complexity of maintaining a sorted list vs inserting all values then sorting

Tags: algorithm

Would the time and space complexity to maintain a list of numbers in sorted order (i.e start with the first one insert it, 2nd one comes along you insert it in sorted order and so on ..) be the same as inserting them as they appear and then sorting after all insertions have been made?

How do I make this decision? Can you demonstrate in terms of time and space complexity for 'n' elements?

I was thinking in terms of phonebook, what is the difference of storing it in a set and presenting sorted data to the user each time he inserts a record into the phonebook VS storing the phonebook records in a sorted order in a treeset. What would it be for n elements?

Comment: n, is not the count o things, its only to distinguish the algorithm from a optimal solution called O(1). The concept is not as straight forward to understand so take your time to understand it. Upvote, keep on it. I am sure you will enjoy this learning.

Comment: Vague title will not be useful to future visitors to the site with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you insert into a sorted list and maintain its sortedness, it is O(logn) comparisons to find where to place it but O(n) movements to place it. Since we insert n elements this is O(n^2). But, I think that if you use a data structure that is designed for inserting sorted data into (such as a binary tree) then do a pass at the end to turn it into a list/array, it is only O(nlogn). On the other hand, using such a more complex data structure will use about O(n) additional space, whereas all other approaches can be done in-place and use no additional space.

Every time you insert into an unsorted list it is O(1). Sorting it all at the end is O(nlogn). This means overall it is O(nlogn).

However, if you are not going to make lists of many elements (1000 or less) it probably doesn't matter what big-O it is, and you should either focus on what runs faster for small data sets, or not worry at all if it is not a performance issue.

Comment: `O(n^2logn)` is a rather odd construction.  As `n` tends to infinity, the `n^2` term is much greater than `log n`, so this is equivalent to just writing `O(n^2)` (which happens to be the known worst-case for insertion sort).

Comment: @Gian That's what my gut was telling me, but why is O(nlogn) worth differentiating from O(n) then?

Comment: Because Big-O notation is really about classifying the growth rates of functions - in this case, `n * log n` grows much more quickly than `O(n)` (particularly as `n` tends towards infinity, which is the other important bit about Big-O notation).

Comment: The total time in the first case is `O(nlogn + n^2)` which is `O(n^2)`. If it was `O(n^2logn)` then it wouldn't be `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @fgb You do an `nlogn` action `n` times, that's `n^2logn` (or `n^2` I guess).

Comment: @Patashu It's not `nlogn` action. It's a `n+logn` action.

Comment: what would it be for a phonebook ?

Comment: @Phoenix I don't understand what you mean by 'phonebook'. What is the context?

Comment: The contacts list on your mobile phone.

Comment: @Phoenix No one is going to have more than, say, a thousand contacts so the last paragraph of my answer now applies.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what data structure you are inserting them in.  If you are asking about inserting in an array, the answer is no.  It takes O(n) space and time to store the n elements, and then O(n log n) to sort them, so O(n log n) total.  While inserting into an array may require you to move \Omega(n) elements so takes \Theta(n^2).  The same problem will be true with most "sequential" data structures.  Sorry.

On the other hand, some priority queues such as lazy leftist heaps, fibonacci heaps, and Brodal queues have O(1) insert.  While, a Finger Tree gives O(n log n) insert AND linear access (Finger trees are as good as a linked list for what a linked list is good for and as good as balanced binary search trees for what binary search trees are good for--they are kind of amazing).

Answer (score 1):

There are going to be application-specific trade-offs to algorithm selection.  The reasons one might use an insertion sort rather than some kind of offline sorting algorithm are enumerated on the [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) wikipedia page.

The determining factor here is less likely to be asymptotic complexity and more likely to be what you know about your data (e.g., is it likely to be already sorted?)

I'd go further, but I'm not convinced that this isn't a homework question asked verbatim.

Comment: that was me and it was because inserting and then sorting is not `O(n^2)` worst case.

Comment: @PhilipJF, I was talking about quicksort, which is `O(n log n)` in the *average* case and `O(n^2)` in the worst case.  Merge sort or something else with `O(n log n)` worst-case is going to have extra space requirements.

Comment: Oh, actually, I was forgetting about non-stable sorting algorithms like heap sort.  I will revise my answer to be less deceptive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you get the same space efficeny with an optimal sort: for example a modified quicksort takes only O(n) extra space with worst case n log n performance if you use BFPRT to do the pivot selection (the constant cost of this can be small if you only run a full BFPRT occasionally, say every 100 iterations).

Answer (score -1):

**Option 1**

Insert at correct position in sorted order.

Time taken to find the position for i+1-th element :`O(logi)`

Time taken to insert and maintain order for i+1-th element: `O(i)`

Space Complexity:`O(N)`

Total time:`(1*log 1 +2*log 2 + .. +(N-1)*logN-1)` =`O(NlogN)`

Understand that this is just the time complexity.The running time can be very different from this.

**Option 2:**

Insert element `O(1)`

Sort elements `O(NlogN)`

Depending on the sort you employ the space complexity varies, though you can use something like quicksort, which doesn't need much space anyway.

In conclusion though both time complexity are the same, the bounds are weak and mathematically you can come up with better bounds.Also note that worst case complexity may never be encountered in practical situations, probably you will see only average cases all the time.If performance is such a vital issue in your application, you should test both sets of code on random sampling.Do tell me which one works faster after your tests.My guess is option 1.